# How to uninstall grails from Windows 7

Tags: grails

I installed grails a couple of years back on my laptop to play with. Since I no longer use it, I tried to uninstall it. However, I can't find a way to do it. I don't want to just delete the folders since there will be environment variables and maybe registry entries that I am worried about. What is the correct way of uninstalling grails from windows?

Comment: What version? 1.0.2 (circa 2008) apparently has an uninstaller - see [here](http://kousenit.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/some-notes-about-the-windows-installer-for-grails/)

Comment: it was pre 0.5, just used 'grails upgrade' to upgrade it to version 1.3.5. Also has another installation on the same laptop which is 2.0.0. Will uninstall it after this task is successful.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 the correct manner to remove an installed version of Grails is:

1. Delete the directory/folder containing the Grails version.
2. Delete the corresponding (if any) folder within `C:\Users\<YOUR USERNAME HERE>\.grails` directory/folder.
3. Remove (or update to another version) the environment variable for `GRAILS_HOME`. This can be done through right clicking on `My Computer` selecting `Properties` then clicking the `Advanced system settings` in the left navigation. From there click the `Environment Variables` button and then delete or edit the `GRAILS_HOME` variable in the `System variables` listing.

Grails does not create any registry entries.

Comment: Thanks. I was more concerned about the registry entries. Good to know that Grails creates none.